# jquery: How do I add validation for check-boxes and radios in this Script?

Tags: jquery

I am working on an app for a client that will need some special validation code. I'm close, but I am stuck on my **checkboxes** and **radio** button validation. I am using the code below to find and filter thru required fields within visible fieldsets.

Thought I could include my input:checkbox fields in this same jquery find/filter, but the validation for checks and radios is not working with the [return $.trim($(this).val()) === ""]. Some how I have to get the **not :checked** included in the find/filter and the include the results in my error message

How can I include/add a search/validate for an non checked/selected, yet required checkboxes and radio button fields?  [**Note**: the third document.ready is the once I am working on]

**my jquery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('fieldset#section-11,fieldset#section-12,fieldset#section-13').hide(); 
            });//end of close all fieldsets


            $(document).ready(function() {
                var projType = new Array(
                        {value : 'Cars', sect_id : 'fieldset#section-11'},
                        {value : 'Planes', sect_id : 'fieldset#section-12'},
                        {value : 'Boats', sect_id : 'fieldset#section-13'}
                    ); //end of projType array

            $("select#1169").on('change',function () {
                var dropDownVal = $(this).val();
                var sect_id ="";
                    $(projType).each(function() {
                        $(this.sect_id).hide(); //hide all section each time you run thru here
                            if(this.value == dropDownVal) 
                                {
                                    $(this.sect_id).show();
                                }
                    });
            });
            });
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnCatchReqFlds").on('click', function(){
        $("#holdErrMsg").empty();
        var reqButEmpty = $('fieldset:visible').find('input[type="text"][class*="-required"],textarea[class*="-required"],select[class*="-required"]').filter(function() 
            {
                    return $.trim($(this).val()) === "";
            });
                    if(reqButEmpty.length>0)
                        {
                            reqButEmpty.each(function() {
                                $('#holdErrMsg').append("Please fill in the " + this.name + "<br />"); 
                            });
                        }
                    return !reqButEmpty.length;
                });
        });

        </script>
```

**My html>>**

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <div id="holdErrMsg"></div>
    <fieldset id="mainSection" name="mainSection">
                <legend style="color:blue; font-weight:bold">Project Overview Section</legend>

                <table style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height: 33px; width: 178px;">Name</td>
                        <td style="height: 33px"><input  id="1125" name="1125" class="1125-required" type="text" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height: 33px; width: 178px;">Email</td>
                        <td style="height: 33px"><input id="1026" name="1026" class="1026-required" type="text" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 178px">Product Title</td>
                        <td><input  id="1089" name="1089" type="text" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 178px">Product Type</td>
                        <td><select id="1169" name="1169">
                        <option value="">Select</option>
                        <option value="Cars">Cars</option>
                        <option value="Boats">Boats</option>
                        <option value="Planes">Planes</option>
                        </select></td>
                    </tr>
                                        <tr><td>
                                        <button id="btnCatchReqFlds" type="button" name="btn">Check Required Fields</button>
                                        </td></tr>
                                    </table>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset id="section-11" name="section-11">
                <legend style="color:fuchsia; font-weight:bold">Car Details Section</legend>

                <table cellpadding="2" style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 334px; height: 35px"><label>Size:*</label></td>
                        <td style="height: 35px"><input id="1245" class="1245-required" name="1245" type="text" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height: 35px; width: 334px">Color:*</td>
                        <td style="height: 35px">
                        <select id="1433" class="1433-required" name="1433">
                        <option value="">Select</option>
                        <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
                        <option value="Blank">Blank</option>
                        <option value="Green">Green</option>
            </select></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 334px">Description:</td>
                        <td>
                        <textarea id="1290" name="1290" class="1290-required" rows="2" style="width: 433px"></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                            </fieldset>

            <fieldset id="section-12" name="section-12">
                <legend style="color:fuchsia; font-weight:bold">Plane Details Section</legend>

                <table cellpadding="2" style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 334px; height: 35px"><label>Size:</label></td>
                        <td style="height: 35px"><input id="1245" name="1245" type="text" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height: 35px; width: 334px">Color*:</td>
                        <td style="height: 35px">
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="1433[]" id="1433[]" value="Orange" class="1433[]-required"/>Orange
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="1433[]" id="1433[]" value="Blue" class="1433[]-required"/>Blue
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="1433[]" id="1433[]" value="Green" class="1433[]-required"/>Green
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 334px">Description:</td>
                        <td>
                        <textarea id="1290" name="1290" rows="2" style="width: 433px"></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                            </fieldset>
            <fieldset id="section-13" name="section-13">
                <legend style="color:fuchsia; font-weight:bold">Boat Details Section</legend>

                <table cellpadding="2" style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 334px; height: 35px"><label>Size:</label></td>
                        <td style="height: 35px"><input id="1245" name="1245" type="text" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height: 35px; width: 334px">Color:*</td>
                        <td style="height: 35px">
                                                <input type="radio" name="1834[]" id="1834[]" value="None" class="valuetext" class="1834[]-required">None
                                                <input type="radio" name="1834[]" id="1834[]" value="All" class="valuetext" class="1834[]-required">All
                       </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 334px">Description:</td>
                        <td>
                        <textarea id="1290" name="1290" rows="2" style="width: 433px"></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                            </fieldset><br>
<fieldset id="section-1011" name="section-1011">
                <legend style="color:green; font-weight:bold">Misc Info Section</legend>

                <table cellpadding="2" style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 334px; height: 35px"><label>Size:</label></td>
                        <td style="height: 35px"><input id="1301" name="1301" type="text" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height: 35px; width: 334px">Color:</td>
                        <td style="height: 35px">
                        <select id="1302" name="1302">
                <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
                        <option value="Blank">Blank</option>
                        <option value="Green">Green</option>
            </select></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 334px">Description:</td>
                        <td>
                        <textarea id="1303" name="1303" class="1303-required" rows="2" style="width: 433px"></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                            </fieldset>


</form>​
        <?php
        // put your code here
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why so many `$(document).ready`? And what's with the indenting?

Comment: Hiya agreed with @elclanrs why `.ready` twice and if I may suggest please take a look into the validation plugin of jquery might suit you, for checkbox use `.is(":checked")` will take a look now, have a nice one, cheers!

Comment: That's right, you could use the [jQuery validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) or my very own plugin [jq-idealforms](https://github.com/elclanrs/jq-idealforms) or many other alternatives.

Comment: Yes, there are some special reasons, that I have to write this code for this particular application. There is more coming that we will need to be able to address, so I want to get this working within my constraints. I have used val plugins in several apps before. This one will have other "things" that will need to be addressed if the app takes the turn that we are planning, so I am trying to get some basics in place so we can easily modify without all the "extras" of plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Hiya **made a demo** from your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/MfVJT/

Little extra **Simple demo using validation plugin** http://jsfiddle.net/9jSGN/

Now it will detect 1433 i.e. checkbox for your validation in the code. Please let me know.

**Just a suggestion** :) I am not sure if you are re-writing validation plugin for your need but please take a look int here: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/

Hope this helps,Please let me know how it goes, this should help, issue was with the field set close tag.

```
$("#signupForm").validate({
    rules:{
        termsConditions : "required"
    }

});
```

Comment: Yes, there are some special reasons, that I have to write this code for this particular application.  There is more coming that we will need to be able to address.  I have used val plugins in several apps before.  This one will have other "things" that will need to be addressed if the app takes the turn that we are planning, so I am trying to get some basics in place so we can easily modify without all the "extras" of plugins.

Comment: @user1176783 No worries bruv! cooleos, does the above helps you :) hope it resolves the issue, have a good one, cheers

Comment: the issue and why I want code based on my flow is the use of fieldsets and selecting required fields within those visible fieldsets and there will be more constraints in the future so I am trying to get code working that can be adjusted more based on several other features we will hopefully have in our apps